# Rails 3.1 Active admin and nested_form and link_to_add not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, nested-forms

I'm using activeadmin (0.3.2) and nested_form (0.2.3).

My Models are:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :event_translations
attr_accessible    :event_translations_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_translations, :allow_destroy => true,
                            :reject_if => proc { |attributes|
                              attributes['title'].blank? and
                                  attributes['description'].blank? and attributes['language_id'].blank?
end


EventTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :language
attr_accessible :description, :title, :event_id, :language_id
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :iso, :name
end
```

In my active_admin event controller, the form is rendered as a partial:

```
form :partial => "form"
```

In my views i have under views/admin/events/_form.html.erb the following:

```
<%= semantic_nested_form_for [:admin, @event] do |f|%>
<% f.object.event_translations.build %>
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :event_translations do |h| %>
<%=h.inputs "Translations" do %>
    <%= h.input :language, :required => true, :as => :select, :prompt => "Select a Language", :collection => Language.all %>
    <%= h.input :title, :label => "Name"%>
    <%= h.input :description %>
    <%= h.link_to_remove "Remove Translation" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>

<%= f.link_to_add "Add Translation", :event_translations %>
...
<% end %>
```

This is rendering the fields fine, but link_to_add and link_to_remove are doing NOTHING on click. //= require jquery_nested_form is added to application.js and the nested_form gem is correctly included in gemfile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!

I'm hating myself right now after hours spent on this...

The solutions was to add

```
//= require jquery_nested_form
```

at the bottom of `active_admin.js` instead of `application.js`.

Comment: me tooo , thanks for the solution for this. i whole day i spent for this